# Mac: Shortcut for switching between two windows of the same application

Tags: macos

I want to switch between two different windows opened in the same desktop on Mac (El Capitan). **I can't do it with `cmd+tab`.** Does anyone knows how to do it?

None of the following shortcuts work as well:
`` cmd+` ``, `` cmd+shift+` ``, `cmd+number`

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that you have the shortcut on in your settings?

Comment: What a pity this question didn't not meet Stack Overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The shortcut is defined in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

[image]

<kbd>⌘`</kbd> is the default, Check the shortcut and if it's enabled at all

Comment: I looked up on `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > Move focus to next window` , and it was set to `cmd+F1`.
Thank you very much!

Comment: to who may be interested: entry does not exist on my system

Answer (score 2):

Using `CMD + Shift + Backtick` allows you to cycle through windows.
To select a specific tab in a window you can use `CMD + a number`.

You may have this disabled in your settings. **System Preference > Keyboard > Shortcuts**

Comment: Hmm. I'm on Sierra. That could potentially be why

Answer (score 1):

Using `cmd+number` you will switch the windows, starting in number 1 to the number of open windows

Comment: it switches between tabs, not windows :(

Comment: `cmd+tab` should work...
At least, works in Sierra, don't know if Capitan works

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue in all [currently released] versions of 10.12 [Sierra].  Although there isn't a solid fix for it the quickest workaround is to go to the Apple menu > System Preferences > Keyboard > Text and in the lower left corner first click the '+' button then click the '-' button, close System Preferences and you should be good to go.  You may need to do this after restarting each time but it only takes a second.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too (MaxOS Mojave)
I knew about this fix:
System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > Move focus to next window
- but could not make it work
The thing is. First just click on the right side of the "Move focus to the next window" you then see the area becomes editable with a line around the symbol to the right. Then you click the combination you want and voila! I noticed when done and then clicked "restore defaults" it went back to not working again. Followed the steps again and all good.
Jonny

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Johnny H works in my Mojave 10.14.2. You obviously cannot assign a key combination already in use in other shortcuts.

> Had this problem too (MaxOS Mojave) I knew about this fix: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > Move focus to next window - but could not make it work The thing is. First just click on the right side of the "Move focus to the next window" you then see the area becomes editable with a line around the symbol to the right. Then you click the combination you want and voila! I noticed when done and then clicked "restore defaults" it went back to not working again. Followed the steps again and all good. Jonny

Answer (score 0):

For me the following works (on my relatively new Macbook Pro 2020):
<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>

A listing in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard` as shown in comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/44624720/845117, currently best rated in this thread, is not existing on my system.

*I do have another older Macbook Air where it is a different shortcut, but I cannot remember if I ever manually changed it; but it was never anything with <kbd>`</kbd> for me.*